# Managing My Hibernate POJO NullPointerException Using Optional

Tags: json, spring, nullpointerexception, option-type

Hi Guys I'm a bit confused in regards to using the Optional with the Java POJO Hibernate. As a Java dev we always complaining about `NullPointerException`, you need to check for null before you access the field.
I have read some posts about this issue but couldn't get a hold of it.
The problem is if we are building a restful API we are dealing with JSON so we have to support the `Optional` with jackson-datatype-jdk8. But the implementation looks a bit not as clean as I thought.

Firstly we need to register JDK8 when registering the ObjectMapper:

```java
private ObjectMapper registerJdkModuleAndGetMapper() {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Jdk8Module module = new Jdk8Module();
    module.configureAbsentsAsNulls(true);
    objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    return objectMapper;
}
```

Secondly we have to use `@JsonProperty` annotation on the instance varObj Constructor:

```java
public Person(
    @JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName,
    @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName,
    @JsonProperty("age") int age,
    @JsonProperty("address") Optional<Address> address,
    @JsonProperty("phone") Optional<String> phone) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.age = age;
  this.address = address;
  this.phone = phone;
}
```

As Intermediate programmer, we always seek help and hints from seniors. Could anyone help me please? Much appreciated

Comment: I am not sure if it is recommended, basically you are adding wrapper and this is internal implementation. Getting null for any object is kind of depends on design and again this should be handled via db i.e. with non null constraint. But I will like to hear more on this

Comment: Correct, that's what we need as DB admin to add NotNull to the DB fields, which would prevent any NULL entry to the DB.

Answer (score -1):

Registering the `Jdk8Module` is mandatory, so no workaround for that.

Regarding `@JsonProperty`, you can remove them since the name of the Java attribute is exactly the same as the configuration you have in `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: -1 because you can also expose through DTO, so please add why might be he have other plans like he is exposing through other media (another topic)

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by your comment? I don't understand how DTOs address the topic in question. And I also don't understand your "please add why might be he have other plans like he is exposing through other media (another topic)" statement. Can you explain please? Thanks.